# Redirigir lineas de log a un fichero, sin mantenerlas en el log principal

Tags: linux

Tengo configurado en RSYSLOG, una regla para que las lineas del Fw (que ya vienen etiquetadas), se redirijan a un fichero específico, tal que asi:

> :msg, startswith, "MyFirewall" -/milog/firewall.log & stop
>
> :msg, regex, "^ *[[0-9]*.[0-9]*] MyFirewall" -/milog/firewall.log &
>   stop

Funciona bien, pero siguen mostrandose en el log principal, ya sea en /var/log/syslog o mostrando con "journalctl -f -a", y el volumen es muy alto y ensucia mucho.

¿Como podría evitar que se muestren en el log general?

Answer (score 0):

Realmente, la regla funciona con la salida de */var/log/syslog*, que veo que no salen las lineas de "*MyFirewall*", pero si analizas con "*journalctl*", no se rige por los filtros de rsyslog, y habría que filtrar en base a sus directivas (units... y demás).